# AJAX/javascript page edit, wait to complete, say ok

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am looking for a way to make a function:

1. Edit a page: document.getElementById("page_0").src = "lots_of_code.php";
2. Wait to complete
3. Edit something else: document.getElementById("page_1").innerHTML = "OK";

If I try to do this, then the second edit starts before the first is done.

How to do this using AJAX/javascript?

Comment: well we may need to see your code?

Comment: my code is the above two lines i posted. the php page takes a few seconds to complete and generates information for the main page. When the information are generated, i want to show an OK message.

Comment: If you are ready to use jquery then you can have a check on `.promise()` function: http://api.jquery.com/promise/